# Как изменить направление отображения значений оси X графика в matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Имеется простенькая программа, строящая линейный график с помощью matplotlib. Поскольку значения по оси X большие по длине, то они перекрывают друг друга. Фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать **вертикальное отображение** значений на оси X? Вот как на фото ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.array(["01.02.2002", "01.02.2003", "01.02.2004", "01.02.2005", "01.02.2006"])
y = np.array([25, 71, 61, 33, 11])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90) # здесь можно установить угол поворота подписей по оси X
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсмотрено на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708190/8324991)

Comment: Вау! Большое спасибо